# order by a string as number sql

Tags: sql, string, pivot, sql-order-by

I have a table like follows, i need to pivot the table with weeks. i could able to create pivot table but the columns order getting shuffled since im ordering a string column. and getting output like 3nd table.

```
MRN                   Weeks
--------------------------------
GIRFTR1H0461081       52
GIRFTR1H0461083       5 - 6
GIRFTR1H0461084       0 - 1
GIRFTR1H0461085       1 - 2
GIRFTR1H0461086       11 - 12
GIRFTR1H0461087       1 - 2
```

I need to get output as a pivot table order by Weeks Like,

```
MRN               | 0 - 1 | 1 - 2 | 5 - 6 |11 - 12|  52
---------------------------------------------------------------
GIRFTR1H0461081   |   0   |   0   |   0   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461083   |   0   |   0   |   1   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461084   |   1   |   0   |   0   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461085   |   0   |   1   |   0   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461086   |   0   |   0   |   0   |  1    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461087       0   |   1   |   0   |  0    |  0
```

When i tried to create this table, the columns order getting shuffled like bellow,

```
MRN               | 0 - 1 | 1 - 2 |11 - 12| 5 - 6 |  52
---------------------------------------------------------------
GIRFTR1H0461081   |   0   |   0   |   0   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461083   |   0   |   0   |   0   |  1    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461084   |   1   |   0   |   0   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461085   |   0   |   1   |   0   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461086   |   0   |   0   |   1   |  0    |  0
GIRFTR1H0461087   |   0   |   1   |   0   |  0    |  0
```

My code is,

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(WeeksBand) 
                          from [test_Tbl]
                          group by WeeksBand
                          order by WeeksBand
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT CurrentSpecialty,' + @cols + ' from 
                (
                   select CurrentSpecialty, WeeksBand, EncounterId
                   from [Tbl_Current_PTL_Test]
                ) x
               pivot 
                (
                   count(EncounterId)
                   for WeeksBand in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p '

   execute(@query);
```

Please help me to sort out my issue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing a string (alpha) sort, and you actually want to be doing a numeric sort.

I'd change the order line from:

order by WeeksBand

to:

order by Cast(SubString(WeeksBand, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', WeeksBand) != 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-', WeeksBand) -1 ELSE LEN(WeeksBand) END) AS INT)

which will convert the first number into an integer value (not string) and then should order correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why a standard pivot query should not work here.  From your expected output it seems you want a `1` as a placeholder for an `MRN` entry which is present in that week, and `0` otherwise.

```
SELECT [MRN],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Weeks] = '0 - 1'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0 - 1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Weeks] = '1 - 2'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1 - 2],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Weeks] = '5 - 6'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [5 - 6],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Weeks] = '11 - 12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [11 - 12],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Weeks] = '52'      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [52]
FROM [yourTable]
GROUP BY [MRN]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should format Week field of first table using 2 digits as:

```
MRN                   Weeks
--------------------------------
GIRFTR1H0461081       52
GIRFTR1H0461083       05 - 06
GIRFTR1H0461084       00 - 01
GIRFTR1H0461085       01 - 02
GIRFTR1H0461086       11 - 12
GIRFTR1H0461087       01 - 02
```